# Exported UV image in Blender 2.82 has opaque background?

Tags: uv, export

In Blender 2.79, UV images have transparent background. But in 2.82, they have gray, opaque background. Opacity setting in the export dialog only changes how light or dark the background is. Feature or bug? For now, I have to manually remove the gray background to work with it.

Comment: Hi. I'm using 2.82 and it seems to be working as expected. Set to 1 the UV islands are filled with grey and the background transparent, set to 0 they are not filled with anything and everything but UV lines are transparent. Were you expecting something else or have I not understood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Render Properties, under Film, check Transparent.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature... I can't think of any use case where that would be useful. The old behavior seems way more predictable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the right way to solve the problem:
In UV editor, open sidebar, view, display, overlays, uncheck "Faces".
The exported image should now has transparent background.